# Some doubts with Shell Scripting.

Tags: linux, shell

I have a couple of requirements to be satisfied using shell scripts. Since I am trio in this area, i would certainly need your help.
1) I have a script which invokes a env-function which will ask for a user input to proceed with the execution. I want my script to supply the answer to this. How can i implement this.

Doing a bit of googling pointed me to an "expect" command, which is unfortunately not installed in my system. Is there any other way to achieve this task?

2) I have another requirement like, the script should find the total number of CPUs in my pc and should append the "-j(2*no. of CPU)" to my make command.

Could somebody please shed some light into how this can be done.

Thanks,
Sen

Comment: please give a little more detail about the `env-function` you are invoking

Comment: That env-function is just a user-added function which is available in the environment.

Comment: did you try the `read` function? for e.g. read the option given by your env-function then enter the relevant answer from the script.

Comment: The word is tyro, not trio, and it is rarely used any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first part has been answered, for the 2nd part you can try something like

```
#!/bin/sh 

cpu=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -e '^processor' | wc -l`
jobs=$(echo "$cpu * 2" | bc)

make -j$jobs
```

Comment: It is the answer below. shellscript < answers. Lets say shellscript first prompts you for an email address, and then Yes/No. Your answers file should basically have email address on one line, and Yes or No on the 2nd line. Thats it. Each line will be sent in to shellscript each time it prompts for a value. Could be shellscript or env-function.

Answer (score 1):

> I have another requirement like, the script should find the total
>   number of CPUs in my pc

You can read the output of 
`/proc/cpuinfo`

or even better:

You can narrow down output with the following command, to display number of processors in the system:

`grep processor /proc/cpuinfo`

Answer (score 0):

you can simply redirect an input to that program. An example with [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall):

```
checkinstall < /path/to/file/with/answers
```

Comment: I dont want to install a new software. Is there any other logic that can be implemented with the existing environment.

Comment: That was an example, made with checkinstall. You can do the same with any program you wish...

Comment: @Sen, for example, you might do `echo y | env-function` assuming the function asks the user for a "y/n" response.